# Data not showing when project is reopened

Tags: qgis, layers

I am a very new QGIS user and I thought I had the hang of it, until I saved a project then when I reopened it to continue work, nothing would show up. All the layers are still there and boxes checked to "show all layers", but none are appearing in the map area of the program. I have tried everything and done numerous searches to figure it out and no luck.

Comment: Are you in the same computer ? Where are your layers stored ? (local, server...). Check the path of your layers in their properties (right-click\properties), something have necesseraly changed.

Comment: What type if layer is it? Temporary layer will be erased when you close the project

Comment: Any chance you could post a screenshot?

Comment: Also check the attribute table to see if the data are here, if not this is a datasource problem. if you can see the data this is a visualisation problem

Comment: Make sure there's a check in the "Render" checkbox (bottom right corner, next to the CRS).